# Printing a range of PDF pages with hyphen in their numeration name

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I've a file.pdf in which some pages have the name C-2, C-3 etc. How can I print for example the pages from C-2 to C-5? If I write the range C-2 - C-5, Adobe is not able to recognize the difference between the hyphen (-) related to the name of the pages and the hyphen (-) related to the syntax of the range.

Answer (score 0):

In adobe, near the the names C-2... there are the corresponding page numbers, so, in order to print the pages from C-2 to C-5, it's necessary to write the corresponding numbers of these pages (number of C-2) - (number of C-3).

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what that might look like, please?

Comment: Hello @spikey_richie sorry it's in italian